# How do I create working links from a data table in a custom component to open up a new window?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I am making a visualforce page to add a custom component to my homepage. I'm trying to add an unread leads table. I'm trying to get the names clickable so my sales team can get to their unread leads from the homepage but I would like it to open up in a new window instead of the created salesforce page.

I used this:

{!ld.name}
         
        
        
              {!ld.company}

[image: How do I make the names turn into hyperlinks instead of adding it into another column?]

[image: and when I click the link, I get this error instead of being directed to the contact. also, how do I make it open in a separate page instead of the visualforce page I created?]

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Lead" recordSetVar="leads" tabstyle="lead" sidebar="false">
<apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">
    <apex:form >
      <apex:panelGrid columns="3">
        <apex:outputLabel value="View:"/>
        <apex:selectList value="{!filterId}" size="1">
          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="list"/>
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!listviewoptions}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
      </apex:panelGrid>

Comment: <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!leads}" var="ld" id="list"> 
      <apex:column value="{!ld.name}"/>
         <apex:column>
              <apex:outputLink value="{!ld.name}">{!ld.name}</apex:outputLink>
         </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!ld.company}"/>
        <apex:column>
              <apex:outputLink value="{!ld.company}">{!ld.company}</apex:outputLink>
         </apex:column>

Comment: <apex:column value="{!ld.industry}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!ld.email}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!ld.phone}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!ld.status}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:form>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring the value of the output link you are forgetting to put the '/' in front of the ID:

Example:

```
<apex:outPutLink value="/{!Account.id}">{!Account.Name}</apex:outputLink>
```

The '/' translates into the relative URL for the value

Comment: It worked. thank you!! Now do you know how I can get the link to open in a new window instead of the visual force page?

Comment: add target="_blank". Its all in the documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputLink.htm and component reference in the VF page editor Ui